# Power Automate Multiple Filter Queries

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am trying to add a Filter Query so that the 'Get Files' action is only returning files which have a field eq to 'Processed', AND a modified date which is older than 2 days. Here is my current Filter Query:

```
Process_x0020_Status eq 'Processed' and Modified le @{addDays(utcNow(),-2)}
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
Error
Action 'Get_files_(properties_only)' failed

Error Details
The expression "Process_x0020_Status eq 'Processed' and Modified le 2021-12-06T10:35:35.5292965Z" is not valid. Creating query failed.
```

Is anyone able to assist please?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, all I had to do was place single quotes around modified expression:

Process_x0020_Status eq 'Processed' and Modified le **'**@{addDays(utcNow(),-2)}**'**